# Terminal saying 'string' is not defined

Tags: python

When I run this program:

```
import time
import sys
login = "Mongoose"
password = "secret"
x = 1

print "Welcome User"
print ""

login = raw_input("Username: ")

password = raw_input("Password: ")

if login == 'Mongoose':
    x = x + 1
else : 
    x = x - 1

if password == 'secret':
    x = x + 1 
else : 
    x = x - 1


if x > 1:
    string = '...\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.10)
time.sleep(0.5)
string = '...\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.10)
time.sleep(0.5)
string = '...\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.10)
time.sleep(0.5)
string = '...\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.10)
time.sleep(0.5)
string = '...\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.10)
time.sleep(0.5)
string = '...\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.10)
time.sleep(0.5)
string = '...\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.10)
time.sleep(0.5)
string = 'Access Granted\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.10)

if x < 1:
    string = 'Access Denied\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.10)
```

It spits out this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "./login3.py", line 27, in <module>
        for char in string:
    NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What is the first `for` loop supposed to print if they don't enter the correct username and password?

Comment: Your use of the `x` variable is very confusing. Why not just write `if login = 'Mongoose' and password = 'secret':` instead of `if x > 1:`?

Comment: [You should switch to Python 3.6 while you are still learning](https://pythonclock.org)

Answer (score 1):

String is not yet defined if x <= 1.

```
if x > 1:
    string = '...\n'
for char in string:  # <<< string is not yet defined if x <= 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if x > 1:
    string = '...\n'
```

This line is causing your error, you should either indent the remainder of your code where you are using `string`. Or you should add an `else` to the if statement to set `string` to a default value.